# knitr how to label and call a figure number in a text

Tags: xetex, knitr

As a knitr beginner I don't know how to label a figure and call it.

For my first figure I've tried the following code witouth succes...

```
<<fig.cap="Dendrogram of GDP (2000-2012)",fig.lp="fig:test">>=  
plot(HClust.1, main= "Cluster Dendrogram GDP")
@
```

`As you can see the figure \ref{fig:test} shows that...`

But after compilation I get `figure ??` instead `figure 1` ...

Comment: You have asked couple questions before, so: Do you know what [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) is?

Comment: Did you compile twice, so that `TeX` had a chance to read the `.aux` file that contains the reference information?

Comment: @tohecz yes i added my MWE.

Comment: Well, you show a one line of a TeX code, which is not a MWE. It might have happened that we have edited almost at the same time and your edit got suppressed, could you please check it? Thanks

Comment: @EthanBolker yeah I compile twice.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

`fig.lp` is not the label of the figure, it is the prefix that is used to create the label. From [the description of `knitr` options](http://yihui.name/knitr/options)

> `fig.lp`: ('fig:'; character) label prefix for the figure label to be used in `\label{}`; the actual label is made by concatenating this prefix and the chunk label, e.g. the figure label for `<<foo-plot>>=` will be `fig:foo-plot` by default

If you don't give your chunks names, they will get a default name such as `unnamed-chunk-1` where the number depends on where it is in the file (and so would make for a bad label to target).

Additionally, to get the graphics into a figure environment, you need to give it a caption. Again from the options description

> `fig.cap`: (`NULL`; character) figure caption to be used in a figure environment in LaTeX (in `\caption{}`); if `NULL` or `NA`, it will be ignored, otherwise a figure environment will be used for the plots in the chunk (output in `\begin{figure}` and `\end{figure}`)

Without this there is no figure environment and therefore no `\label{}` created.

Putting this together, here is a MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}

<<myfig, fig.cap=''>>=
plot(1:10)
@

As you can see the figure \ref{fig:myfig} shows that...

\end{document}
```

This creates a `.tex` file, the relevant (but incomplete) excerpt of which is

```
\begin{knitrout}
\definecolor{shadecolor}{rgb}{0.969, 0.969, 0.969}\color{fgcolor}\begin{kframe}
\begin{alltt}
\hlfunctioncall{plot}(1:10)
\end{alltt}
\end{kframe}\begin{figure}[]

\includegraphics[width=\maxwidth]{figure/myfig} \caption[]{\label{fig:myfig}}
\end{figure}


\end{knitrout}


As you can see the figure \ref{fig:myfig} shows that...
```

You can see that the `\label{}` and `\ref{}` match up now.

See also more discussion about this in a [related Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14991735/892313).